# How to unit test TwilioChatClient on iOS with Swift and CocoaPods

Tags: ios, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

Since Twilio Programmable Chat SDK is quite complex I sometimes run into scenarios hard to replicate in the app, so I decided to do some unit tests.
The problem is, I am unable to initialize the `TwilioChatClient`. Do you have an idea what am I doing wrong?

**Xcode debug console**

```
Test Case '-[ONNTests.ONNTests testTwoClientCreation]' started.
    0x7000065c6000 | 12/18/13:26:18.979 | FATAL    | Chat-iOS | Error instantiating client framework path.
    0x7000065c6000 | 12/18/13:26:18.980 | DEBUG    | Chat-iOS | releasing chat client instance: <TwilioChatClient: 0x7fcf01552c20>
```

**Podfile**

```
target 'MyTests' do
  pod 'TwilioChatClient', '~> 2.1.0'
end
```

**Code**

```
import XCTest
import TwilioChatClient

class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    var client1: TwilioChatClient?

    let e1 = XCTestExpectation(description: "Download Twilio token 1")
    let e2 = XCTestExpectation(description: "Create client 1 successfully")

    func testTwilioClientCreation() {
        TwilioChatClient.setLogLevel(.debug)

        getToken { [unowned self] token in
            self.e1.fulfill()
            TwilioChatClient.chatClient(withToken: token, properties: nil, delegate: self) { [unowned self] (result, client) in
                if result.isSuccessful() {
                    self.client1 = client
                    self.e11.fulfill()
                }
            }
        }

        wait(for: [e1, e2], timeout: 20.0)
    }

    func getToken(completion: @escaping (_ token: String) -> Void) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm not too informed around testing in iOS but I have asked around internally to see if anyone else can help. Are you retrieving the token from an external service in this test? That would seem flaky to me in general. Also, instantiating a full `TwilioChatClient` within a test is going to set up all sorts of connections to Twilio's service too. Can you look into mocking the Twilio service itself?

Comment: Hi @philnash thanks for your response. Retrieving the token is working fine for me. This seems to be some complication with the project setup, paths or something similar. I know it's a good idea and common approach to mock services like this in testing, but I am not trying to test my app, but Twilio itself. I already found 3 bugs in Programmable Chat SDK for iOS (they're already on GitHub Issues or in your Support Tickets), so I am just trying have an environment where I am able to test/replicate some complex scenarios easily (create channel, invite, accept, leave, delete, etc...).

Comment: Then I can't help I'm afraid, I just don't know enough about testing in iOS. Thanks for helping to test the SDK though, I hope the bugs you are finding are fixed swiftly for you.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-ios/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the TwilioChatClient may be being brought in via the target under test, not the test directly.  This can cause an issue in our ability to find resources contained in the framework which is message you are seeing.

To work around this, please ensure the TwilioChatClient framework is declared as a dependency to your test target directly, for example:

```
target 'TestingSample' do
  pod 'TwilioChatClient', '~> 2.1.0'

  target 'TestingSampleTests' do

  end
end
```

Please also note it is important to shutdown the client when you are done with it, either at the end of your test method or in a shared tear down method.

```
wait(for: [e1, e2], timeout: 20.0)

self.client1?.shutdown()
self.client1 = nil
```

A working sample project can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1anoaSIKv1c3_gHtPsKWv3-c3PScNmIw6/view?usp=sharing).

We'll work on making this smoother in a future release, please let us know if the above resolves the unit testing issue you're seeing or if we can help further.

Comment: This doesn't work in the normal case where the test target is testing code in the app target which uses TwilioChatClient. Please see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-ios/issues/9. I hope this can be resolved, as it is important to be able to test our code.